# sorting for worksheets in 1 workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched the net for a macro that can help me to do sorting for worksheets in a workbook and modified it a little ( adding the exclude worksheets)

```
Sub SortDataWorksheets()

Dim wsh As Worksheet
For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If wsh.Name <> "Dashboard" And wsh.Name <> "rawdata" And wsh.Name <> "template" And wsh.Name <> "macros instructions" And wsh.Name <> "Sheet1" _
    And wsh.Name <> "Sheet2" And wsh.Name <> "inputlist" And wsh.Name <> "ProductList" And wsh.Name <> "NA" Then

    'sort columns A to AL based on data in column B
    wsh.Columns("A:AL").Sort key1:=Range("B3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

However, this doesnt work as excel will throw the

```
Run Time error '1004' :
The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort...
```

My data starts from Row 3 onwards, 1st 2 rows are headers. How do i exclude the first 2 rows for sorting?

Answer (score 1):

Change from:

```
wsh.Columns("A:AL").Sort key1:=Range("B3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

To:

```
wsh.Columns("A:AL").Sort key1:=wsh.Range("B3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Because if you do not refer to the parent worksheet, VBA takes as parent worksheet the `ActiveSheet` or the sheet in which the code is. Both would return an error in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Sub SortDataWorksheets()

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With wsh
            If .Name <> "Dashboard" And .Name <> "rawdata" And .Name <> "template" And _
                .Name <> "macros instructions" And .Name <> "Sheet1" _
                And .Name <> "Sheet2" And .Name <> "inputlist" And _
                .Name <> "ProductList" And .Name <> "NA" Then

                LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

                'sort columns A to AL based on data in column B
                .Range("A2:AL" & LastRow).Sort key1:=.Range("B3"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Notice the use of a specific range instead of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to read a `Select Case` rather than multiple `IF..AND..THEN` when ignoring sheets.

The code below will adjust to how many rows contain data in column B.

I'm still not sure which is the preferred method of sorting - single line, or what the macro recorder returns (similar to below).

```
Public Sub SortDataWorksheets()

    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long

    For Each wsh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case wsh.Name
            Case "Dashboard", "rawdata", "template", "macros instructions", _
                 "Sheet1a", "Sheet2a", "inputlist", "ProductList", "NA"

                 'Do nothing

            Case Else

                lLastRow = wsh.Cells(wsh.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

                With wsh.Sort

                    With .SortFields
                        .Clear
                        .Add Key:=Range("B5:B" & lLastRow), _
                             SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                             Order:=xlAscending, _
                             DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                    End With

                    .SetRange Range("A5:C" & lLastRow)
                    .Header = xlNo
                    .MatchCase = False
                    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                    '.SortMethod = xlPinYin 'Only need if sorting Chinese characters.
                    .Apply

                End With

        End Select
    Next wsh

End Sub
```